# Use Django AUTH_USER model to pass data with JWT Token (Eg.first_name, last_name)

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm working on Django RF using ModelViewSet where I'll be using JWT Token Authentication. I want to use default django auth_user model rather than creating new custom user model.

```
#serializer.py
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username','first_name')
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
        data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
        data.pop('refresh', None) # remove refresh from the payload
        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

        # Add extra responses here
        data['username'] = self.user.username
        data['first_name'] = self.user.first_name
        data['last_name'] = self.user.last_name
        return data

views.py
class TokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
# Replace the serializer with your custom
serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
# token_obtain_pair = TokenObtainPairView.as_view()



class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username','first_name')
@classmethod
def get_token(cls, user):
    token = super().get_token(user)
    token['username'] = user.username
    token['first_name'] = user.first_name
    return token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don´t set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'` in settings.py, you will use `User` by default instead of `MyUser`.

#### settings.py

And if you use [simplejwt](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you have to assign the authentication class.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        ...
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
    ...
}
```

---

##### CustomTokenObtainPairView without customizing token

> Okay got it. Thanks alot @Klim Bim. Can you do me a favour. Can you tell me how can i add other fields with simple-jwt token. I have tried using Custom TokenObtaibPairView' but all i'm getting is user_id.

Either you can customize [token claims](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html#customizing-token-claims) or you can add data to response.

##### serializer.py

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['username'] = user.username
        token['first_name'] = user.first_name

        return token
```

##### views.py

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):

   serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

      response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
      response.data['custom_key'] =  'my_custom_data'
      
      return response
```

##### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('token/', CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
]
```

##### postman

[image]

Comment: Thank you and can you please tell me how can i create serializer using auth_user model for username and password and how can i pass these serializer for creating login api using modelviewset

Comment: You protect your views with e.g. `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]` not your serializer.  If you want to create a view that resets password and makes other things you need a `ModelSerializer` that uses `model = User` [drf permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/), [drf user viewset example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)

Comment: If you aren´t logged in the view denys your get-request where you set `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]`

Comment: Thanks alot. So how can i pass username and password for my frontend page. Do i need to create superuser to get access.

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean. You can create a superuser for django with `python manage.py createsuperuser` who has full privileges. If you want to create a reagular user, you can `POST` one. It is not necessary to have a superuser. Only you want to create user that are not active by default and the superuser has the rights to active them.

Comment: Actually i'm using Django Rest API and for front end ASP.Net. So for logging i'll create a superuser who has full privileges. So all i wanna ask is do i need to create a login api or not

Comment: At my point of view you don´t need a login api. Django can handle the logging and you can display the logging entries at a protected view. The superuser can access that view and read the entries. Long story short, use `createsuperuser`. `POST` your credentials (superuser) to `Simple JWT`´s `path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()...)` and get the token. `GET` your data of the protected view with using the obtained token. [Usage of simple jwt](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#usage)

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks alot @Klim Bim. Can you do me a favour. Can you tell me how can i add other fields with simple-jwt token. I have tried using Custom TokenObtaibPairView' but all i'm getting is user_id.

Comment: I tried customising by your code but getting nothing. Even i have updated my post with a code and i'm getting is user_id. Can you please check and let me know what;s wrong.

Comment: Because you are using `validate()` instead of `get_token()` -->  [claims](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html). `valdiate` will be used if you add data to a serializer  e.g. `serializer = MySerializer(data=data_to_serialize)`

Comment: I tried using get_token(). But all am getting is user_id. Post Updated.

Comment: {
  "token_type": "access",
  "exp": 1631534090,
  "jti": "d81441fcde654b0ca43b52ee660a07b7",
  "user_id": 1
}

Comment: Do you call the correct view? Are you calling TokenObtainPairView.as_view() or MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view() . My test worked well and got username and first_name.  Django cannot determin what custom view it shall use. You inherit `TokenObtainPairView` and use the same name for your own view. Maybe you should adjuste your imports as well.

Comment: I'm calling `TokenObtainPairView.as_view()`. Is it correct or should I call `MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view()`

Comment: Can you even tell me where you are able to get the data. Are you using Postman or other extensions or through terminal?

Comment: Like I wrote. You can use MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view() because you are using a custom serializer that is assigned to that view. If you use your TokenObtainPairView.as_view() you have to adjuste your imports in urls.py and they have to point to your TokenObtainPairView. I use Postman. I updated my code.

Comment: Thanks alot @Klim Bim. You helped alot. I have used auth_user model now. Incase in future i need to pass other model with token, how i need to pass it?

Comment: @Aakash Bhaikatti Like I wrote in my post. Adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'` in settings.py and creating `class MyUser(django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser)` is what you can do. Would you mark it is as solved if it helped?

Comment: Thanks @KlimBim and have marked it as solved. So to get other model data i would need to create a Custom User.

Comment: @AakashBhaikatti [substituting user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: Thank you @KlimBim for your valuable time & helping.